# Netlify is retuning a 404 when I upload my React application?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

So I am uploading a single page client side react app on netlify. And I get a "404 page not found" message when I deploy it.

I have tried a _redirects file with `/*    /index.html   200` in the public folder, but that did not work
I tried changing the settings in build command to "CI=  npm run build" , that also did not do anything other than cause another error saying "Command failed with exit code 254: CI= npm run build" so I edited it back the blank default value for the build command.

https://jolly-bhaskara-654af5.netlify.app/

https://github.com/moedeera/MySite2/tree/main/client

Here is my folder structure

```
client-----
           |
           |
          Node_modules
          package.json
          package-lock.json
         .gitignore
         .readme
         .src
         .Public ----------
                           |
                           |
                            _redirects
                            index.html
                            manifest.json  
                            robots.txt
                            favicon.ico
```

my package.json reads

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me understand what is going wrong and how can I deploy this properly ?

Comment: Why is the  "src" and "public" directories hidden? .src and .Public why? Kindly provide the link to your project if it is hosted anywhere.